# XCode: compiling doesn't always replace plist?

Tags: xcode, macos, plist

I have an application and I will sometimes just change the plist, say to change the version number. Sometimes I'll actually make a change to the code, AND the version number....in the latter case, SOMETIMES the version number of the resulting app will change, in the former it will never change. The only way I've found that surely does it right is when I delete the .app before compiling.

In case it matters, the resulting app is being put in a folder that isn't in the build folder, but I doubt that that's relevant. any thoughts?

Comment: Do you put the plist into the package as part of the Copy Files build process?

Comment: No, because it gives me a warning when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete the whole app, just open it up and delete the Info.plist.  I know that's still not very satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

if I make clean before each build, that seems to work as well, but that's REALLY slow in a big project...

It appears that if I include the plist in the target, it WILL update it... however that gives me a warning. fortunately, it's only one warning and I can ignore it...